# input a form option into databse mySQL and php

Tags: php

```
<select name="direction">
    <option value="<a href='1.php'>1</a>">1</option>
    <option value="<a href='2.php'>2</a>">2</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to insert a href into a database but the double quotes are messing it up how do I properly use double or single quotes in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
<select name="direction">
    <option value='<a href=1.php>1</a>'>1</option>
    <option value='<a href=2.php>2</a>'>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do like that. Just try like below:

Your html will be like this;

```
<select name="direction" onchange="onSelect()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

And Javascript will be like this-

```
function onSelect() {
    if (document.getElementById("direction").value == "1"){
        window.location.href = "1.php";
    }     
    elseif (document.getElementById("direction").value == "2"){
                window.location.href = "2.php";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your html before inserting it into database. You can use `addslashes(string $str)` to escape values which contains HTML content.

**on server side**

```
$myvalue = "<a href='1.php'>1</a>";  // value from selected option
$escaped_myvalue = addslashes($myvalue); // $myvalye becomes "<a href=/'1.php/'>1</a>"
inser_into_table($escaped_myvalue);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php